# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' на хостинге

Tags: django, wsgi

При развёртке сайта на хостинге timeweb, выдаёт 500 ошибку. Где-то намудрил в wsgi.py, так как не оставил дефолтный код

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at info@timeweb.ru to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

посмотрел error_logs, вот трейсбэк

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/cr51888/newsite/public_html/Django/Django/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Ну и вот код wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
import platform
#путь к проекту, там где manage.py
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/cr51888/newsite/public_html/Django')
#путь к фреймворку, там где settings.py
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/cr51888/newsite/public_html/Django/Django')
#путь к виртуальному окружению myenv
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/cr51888/newsite/myenv/lib/python{0}/site-packages'.format(platform.python_version()[0:3]))
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/c/cr51888/newsite/myenv/lib/python3.8/sitepackages')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "Django.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Почему в файле wsgi.py написано cx53558, а в тексте ошибки написано cr51888?

Comment: @andreymal поправил, в любом случае выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Ну а в упомянутом виртуальном окружении Django вообще установлен?

Comment: @andreymal Да, конечно